# SCTP: Issue with sending data over 100msec delay

Tags: sockets, client-server, sctp

I am using a SCTP client to send 1000byte data to another SCTP server over a 100m sec delay link. The delay is configured using traffic control(tc) and netem available in Linux

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms
```

The code I have used is from [SCTP Multihoming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342617/sctp-multihoming). I have set roundtrip time(max) to 60 seconds and heartbeat to 10sec. Now the issue I am facing is that I can send around 3 to 4 packets of 1000 bytes properly. After that the "Connection reset by peer" happens and because of that I am not able to send any more packets. Can you please let me know what I need to do to send SCTP data over high latency link. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could fix the issue. The issue is caused by a NAT box in between the SCTP client and server. The NAT changes the ip address and during the SCTP heart beat message exchange, since the ip address is different, the client cant find the right ip address and because of this SCTP association fails. So SCTP server sends an ABORT to the client. I removed the NAT and everything went fine.

Comment: Isn't that more of a broken NAT configuration?

Comment: SCTP over NAT is currently a bit broken. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-behave-sctpnat-05 for an IETF working doc that proposes a fix.