# Can SOL_SOCKET be used for any optname?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, sctp, setsockopt

I am very new to SCTP programming and while troubleshooting and referring to a book (Unix Network Programming, by W.Richard Stevens) I came across something ambiguous. They have used the level name as SOL_SOCKET [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342617/sctp-multihoming) and [here](http://www.opensourceforu.com/2011/12/socket-api-part-5-sctp/) for option name (optname) values SCTP_INITMSG and SCTP_EVENTS which are supposed to be used with IPPROTO_SCTP, according to the book. Both the codes work fine, so I must be missing something and I feel I am missing something pivotal. What is it? Please help me through this. Thank You.

Comment: They must have the same numerical values. IPPROTO_SCTP is only for use in socket() IIRC. The book could be wrong, although in over twenty years I've never found a bug in it. I would have thought you should use SOL_SCTP for SCTP_* options in setsockopt().

Comment: I know I am sticking to the book a little too much, but there is no level named SOL_SOCKET, the SCTP_* options are given in a table  against IPPROTO_SCTP level. Moreover I just found out that this page ---> http://www.opensourceforu.com/2011/12/socket-api-part-5-sctp/  also states that "To manipulate sockets at sockets API level, the level is specified as SOL_SOCKET". If you could explain that statement, that would help me alot.

Comment: Also the book might be outdated, its the Volume 1, Third Edition, that I have here.